# flexbox space-between not working on img and button element

Tags: css, flexbox

I am creating a navigation bar, and i can't space the image and the button.

The Code file:

```css
  .mobile-navP4 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
  }
```

```html
<div class="mobile-navP4">
  <img class="logo-project-4" src="" alt="Logo Image" />
  <button class="toggle-iconP4">
    <i class="fas fa-bars fa-lg"></i>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: It is applying, maybe your icon is not showing up. You can add a letter to it to check

Comment: Because you use `flex`, the button goes to the right. What would you like to achieve?

Comment: The icon is showing, and I am trying to achieve a navigation bar that has the logo as image on the left, and the font awesome icon as my toggle button on the right.
The image and the icon are right next to each other on the left, and If I apply a gap, it is working, but the space between is not

Comment: As far as I understand you want the image to the left and the button to the right. This is exactly how it looks in your code.